# Where does the Grails Spring Security plugin save currentUser in HttpSession

Tags: grails, spring-security, httpsession

it is famous to get the current user by calling :

```
springSecurityService.currentUser ;
```

Does Spring Ssecurity API save this object in `HttpSession`. if So, how to access to this object from session .

i.e:  `session['currentUser']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

As you showed in your answer the `Principal` is stored in the session, but that's the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` instance that was created by the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`. The default implementation of that in the plugin is `grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser` but that's easily customized.

The `UserDetails` instance is typically a lightweight object, just containing the username and hashed password, a few locked/enabled booleans, and a collection of `GrantedAuthority` instances to store role names. I often recommend that users extend this to also contain data that's useful but unlikely to change during a login session, e.g. full name, to avoid going to the database to retrieve it. Since the `UserDetails` is stored in the session and easily accessible via `springSecurityService.principal` it's a great place to store data like this.

But it is not the same thing as what's returned from `getCurrentUser()`/`currentUser` - this is the GORM user/person domain class that was loaded by the `UserDetailsService` to create the `UserDetails` instance. It can have a lot more data associated with it, lazy-loaded hasMany collections, etc. It's often a rather large object that should *not* be stored in the session. Doing so does make its data conveniently available, but will affect scalability because you waste server memory and limit the number of concurrent sessions a server can have. And it's a disconnected Hibernate object, so to use it for most persistence-related actions requires that you reload the instance anyway, often with `merge()`. That loads the whole thing from the database, so it's a lot more efficient to store the extra data you need in the `UserDetails`, along with the id of the instance so you can easily retrieve the instance as needed. That's what `getCurrentUser()`/`currentUser` does - it uses the id if it's available for a `get()` call, or the username for the equivalent of a `findByUsername()` call (which should be around the same cost if the username has a unique index).

Answer (score 0):

After HttpSession inspecting `session.getAttributeNames()`, i want to share my result :

```
session.getAttribute('SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT').authentication.principal
```